# Get Element with Mootools css selector for same element with same id

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a table which has several links in td tag with the same id,can I get the link's inner html respectively.I want to know

1. Why cant I add events with all the same elements with same id as **$$('#update_room_link')** but class selector as
   **$$('.update_room_link')** works
2. 2.How to get the **innerhtml** for respective links. Same id but different innerhtml upon clicking links, heres the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v64RY/1/)

the is what I want -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="update_room_link">Edit</a>

        </td>
        <td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="update_room_link">Delete</a>

        </td>
        <td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="update_room_link">Add</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

javascript tried as

```
$$('#update_room_link').addEvent('click', function () {
    alert();// get innerHtml of Edit,Delete or Add as clicked

})
```

**Questions updated**
I have a html SELECT in a table row,this row has many table data.I want to get the value/innerhtml of a table data which has its id set (and within the SAME row).Or how can I get an immediate grand-parent of a child FROM a child..is it possible

```
<tr> 
<td id="id">100</td> 
<td>Australi</td> 
<td>BAT</td> 
<td>2014-02-23</td> 
<td>pending</td> 
</tr>
```

[image]

I want the innerhtml of name of the SELECTED option. All the select has same class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID must be unique in a html element, that's why you can not use the same ids on your `a`  tags so `$$('#update_room_link')` is for all elements.

You can use the class and can get inner html like this

```
$$('.update_room_link').addEvent('click', function () {
    alert(this.innerHTML); //here you will get the respective inner HTML
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v64RY/2/)

Please see [ID shold be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id)

If you want use id then it should be unique,  in that case you will have to attach each function independntly, which is not good practice, like

```
$$('#update_room_link1').addEvent('click', function () {....
$$('#update_room_link2').addEvent('click', function () {....
```

Comment: Thank u very much bro, wtf..how can I forget id is unique...sigh!!. cud u pls help a bit further. I have a html SELECT in a table row,this row has many table data.I want to get the value/innerhtml of a table data which has its id set (and within the SAME row).Or how can I an immediate grand-parent of a child FROM a child..is it possible
<tr>
<td id="id">100</td>
<td>Australi</td>
<td>BAT</td>
<td>2014-02-23</td>
<td>pending</td>
</tr>

Comment: Can you please put all html and javascript at jsfiddle that I can view it?

Comment: opps. I got the value by alert( ((this.parentNode).parentNode).children[1].innerHTML); ...LOL, is there a shortcut version. Thanx

Comment: Great you have done it.:)  `this.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML`, there is no need to use parenthesis near the `parentNode`

Answer (score 1):

I add this answer after you already accepted a answer, just to complete a bit.

If you want to add event to one element **by ID** you can use

```
$('update_room_link').addEvent('click', function () {
```

it will also work with

```
$$('#update_room_link').addEvent('click', function () {
```

To add events to many elements, **by CLASS** you can use

```
$$('.update_room_link').addEvent('click', function () {
```

To **get the HTML** the recommended method by MooTools is

```
element.get('html');
```

but will also work with

```
element.innerHTML
```

since mootools uses native elements

Comment: @Sergio no worries pal :) +1ed obv! Great!